# I have a homework assignment to program a prime number generator

Tags: python, generator, primes

The rules for the assignment regarding asking for help are as follows:
I am allowed to ask for help if I am confused with my code, and cannot copy and paste code from others. I must understand all code, and what each function and piece of the code is doing. We learned about the **next** function, and we have to use a class to make the generator. We also learned about StopIteration, but when would I use that? My code doesn't seem to work properly when I am using it. Maybe I am putting it in the wrong place.

I was having a bit of trouble with ending the generator, and it also kept returning None when the number wasn't prime, when I wanted it to keep going instead to the next prime number. How could I make it so it ends, and also keeps going until it reaches the next prime number instead of returning None?
This is what I tried so far:

```
    class PrimeGenerator:
        def __init__(self, maximum):
            self.maximum = maximum + 1
            self.count = 0
    
        def __next__(self):
            if self.count < self.maximum:
                for num in range(self.count, self.maximum):
                    for divisor in range(2, self.count + 1):
                        if num // divisor != num / divisor:
                            print(f'number is prime, it is {num} and the count is {self.count}, and the divisor is {divisor}')
                            self.count += 1
                            return num
                        else:
                            break
    
                    self.count += 1
    
    my_gen = PrimeGenerator(7)
    print(next(my_gen))
    print(next(my_gen))
    print(next(my_gen))
    print(next(my_gen))
    print(next(my_gen))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, there is an argument which is the maximum amount of values I want to go through when trying to find prime numbers. As a result, I want it to stop when it reaches that maximum amount. I tried using an if statement to check if the amount of values looped through was greater than the maximum, else I wouldn't run the for loops. However, this still returns None. I want to stop it from going past the maximum amount.

Comment: Your code shouldn't assume how many primes it is going to get back, right? What if you wanted all of them to 1000? That would be an awful lot of extra lines of code :o). 
 Those `next()` calls should be a single call in a loop. Or, even better, a `for-in` loop.  See the bottom of my answer for both forms of using an iterator that keeps returning values until it doesn't.

Comment: You can speed up the search because 2 is the only even prime.  Also, apart from 2 and 3, all primes are of the form `6n-1` or `6n+1` for some `n`.  That lets you skip over a lot of non-primes during your search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've implemented is an "iterator", but not a true "generator". Per the Python docs:

> Python provides generator functions as a convenient shortcut to
> building iterators. Generator functions allow you to declare a
> function that behaves like an iterator, i.e. it can be used in a for
> loop.

```
def PrimeGenerator(maximum):
    for num in range(2, maximum + 1):
        for divisor in range(2, num):
            if num // divisor == num / divisor:
                break
        else:
            yield num


for p in PrimeGenerator(7):
    print(p)
```

Result:

```
2
3
5
7
```

For completeness, and to show how much of a code savings you get with true generators, here's the same logic as a classic iterator:

```
class PrimeGenerator:

    def __init__(self, highest):
        self.next_candidate = 2
        self.highest_number = highest

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        for num in range(self.next_candidate, self.highest_number + 1):
            for divisor in range(2, num // 2 + 1):
                if num // divisor == num / divisor:
                    break
            else:
                self.next_candidate = num + 1
                return num
        raise StopIteration

    def next(self):
        return self.__next__()

for p in PrimeGenerator(7):
    print(p)
```

to be sure it worked, I also tried using the pattern of calling next() on the iterator.  This gives the same result:

```
p = PrimeGenerator(7)
while True:
    try:
        print(p.next())
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Yes, but I would need to be able to use the next method. So I could do `next(my_gen)`. This isn't a proper generator, it needs to have the `__next__` method or `__iter__`.

Comment: The examples of generators they showed us in class had the `__next__` method.

Comment: You might be right.  I've just only worked with the `yield` kind then.  `yield` is so cool though!  There's so much more code otherwise.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator#:~:text=Create%20Generators%20in%20Python,-It%20is%20fairly&text=It%20is%20as%20easy%20as,it%20becomes%20a%20generator%20function. This was the documentation on the generators.

Comment: Ah...I just read something too.  It seems that an Iterator can also be called a Generator, but then there are true Generator Functions that implement an Iterator in a single function call.  The Python docs state "Python provides generator functions as a convenient shortcut to building iterators."  So it's a matter of semantics.

Comment: I tried replacing my return with yield inside the next method. This resulted in a generator object being returned, and I was able to convert it into a list, as the values had been yielded.

Comment: I just looked at that link you gave above.  It confirms what I said above.  A generator is a single function that uses `yield` to return multiple values. - But hey, it sounds like you've got your code working via @BattleMage_'s answer, and that's what your instructor wants to see.  I think it's all good!

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the class, define the current number and the highest number. The point of having a highest number is that when we encounter a number which is greater than the highest number, we end our prime number generation. To do that, we raise a `StopIteration` exception.

In the `__next__` method, we check if the number is prime. If it is, we return it else we move forward to the next one and repeat the process.

```py
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


class PrimeGenerator:
    def __init__(self, highest=100):
        self.current = 2
        self.highest_number = highest

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            if self.current > self.highest_number:
                raise StopIteration
            if is_prime(self.current):
                self.current += 1
                return self.current - 1
            self.current += 1


prime_generator = PrimeGenerator(10)
print(next(prime_generator))
print(next(prime_generator))
print(next(prime_generator))
print(next(prime_generator))
print(next(prime_generator))

# For large maximum values
for prime in PrimeGenerator(100):
    print(prime)
```

Comment: You don't need to `throw StopIterator` if you know how many times to call `next()`.  Your code shouldn't assume how many primes it is going to get back, right?  What if you wanted all of them to 1000?  Those `next()` calls should be a single call in a loop.

Comment: If I want it till a 1000, then I would set that in the constructor. Besides, we definitely need to `raise StopIteration` because, if we decide to loop over the `prime_generator`, the `for` loop, loops until the `StopIteration` exception is raised.

Comment: I'm sorry.  My comment wasn't very clear.  I was commenting on the fact that you are hard coding some number of `print(next(prime_generator))` lines.  I was really pointing out what you are saying...that you want to iterate in a loop rather than adding 163 more copies of `print(next(prime_generator))` to go to 1000.

Comment: makes sense now. I will update the answer with the loop example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop the generator, all you have to do is raise StopIteration at the end of the function.

I believe that the prime finding logic for your code is wrong, so I have written my own prime test. Each time `__next__` is called, it continues to test integers from count and yields if they are prime. We only have to loop up to sqrt(num) to check if it's prime, because any factors above sqrt(num) will have a corresponding factor that is smaller. You can also use the modulo operator to easily check for factors, rather than dividing.

I also added `__iter__` so that the generator can be used in a for loop.

```py
class PrimeGenerator:
    def __init__(self, maximum):
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.count = 2

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while self.count <= self.maximum:
            num = self.count
            is_prime = True
            for divisor in range(2, 1 + int(num ** 0.5)):
                if self.count % divisor == 0:
                    is_prime = False
                    break
            if is_prime:
                self.count += 1
                return num
            self.count += 1
        raise StopIteration()
```

Comment: That code worked, and prevented nothing from being returned as it was the last line to execute under the __next__ method. Thanks a lot, I hadn't thought of raising the StopIteration in that way.

Comment: Your code can be a bit more DRY if you move the statement `self.count += 1` above the `if`.  Then you don't need to have two copies of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, and comments that follow, leave it unclear what `maximum` means.  I.e. the *number of primes* the prime generator should produce or the *largest number* it should consider.  First let's consider it limits the *number* of primes produced:

```
class PrimeGenerator:
    def __init__(self, maximum):
        self.maximum = maximum  # how many primes we'll generate
        self.count = 0  # how many primes we've generated
        self.number = 1  # prime the prime pump

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count < self.maximum:
            if self.count == 0:  # for speed, treat 2 as a special case
                self.count += 1
                return 2

            while True:
                self.number += 2

                for divisor in range(3, int(self.number ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
                    if self.number % divisor == 0:
                        break
                else:  # no break 'for'
                    self.count += 1
                    return self.number  # found a prime

        raise StopIteration()  # exceeded maximum

if __name__ == '__main__':

    generator = PrimeGenerator(25)

    while True:
        try:
            print(next(generator), end=" ")

        except StopIteration:
            print()
            break
```

Now let's modify the code so that the `maximum` argument represents the *largest* number considered:

```
class PrimeGenerator:
    def __init__(self, maximum):
        self.maximum = maximum  # largest number we'll consider
        self.number = 2  # prime the prime pump

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.number <= self.maximum:
            if self.number == 2:  # for speed, treat 2 as a special case
                self.number += 1
                return 2

            while self.number < self.maximum:

                for divisor in range(3, int(self.number ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
                    if self.number % divisor == 0:
                        break
                else:  # no break 'for'
                    prime = self.number
                    self.number += 2
                    return prime  # found a prime

                self.number += 2

        raise StopIteration()  # exceeded maximum
```

These examples treat 2 as a special case, subsequently avoiding even numbers as candidates and/or divisors as in the other examples.  (The benefit of doing this is a ~4x speed up.)